# Forwarding traffic from a router through a Comcast router/modem

Tags: networking, network-traffic

I don't trust Comcast to do networking for me with regards to securiry or privacy, and I need to find out how to forward my network traffic through this new closed router they gave me.  What is the best method to forward traffic from my phones and computer to the internet through this new router Comcast gave me?  DMZ, port forwarding, or virtual servers?

My personal router is an TP-Link Archer C7.

Answer (score 0):

Call your ISP to put the modem in bridge mode. Thats all, after you put the router you want behind it.